# Cannot create project in eclipse with the gwt-maven-plugin

Tags: eclipse, gwt, plugins, maven

I went to new >> other >> maven project >> selected nexus indexer or all the other catalogs, but there is no gwt-maven-plugin. I've tried to add it with the foolowing details:

group id: org.codehaus.mojo

artifact id: gwt-maven-plugin

version: 2.4.0

repository url: repo1.maven.org

But I get the follwing error:

"Can't resolve Archetype org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not resolve artifact org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:pom:2.4.0"

Does anyone know why this is happening?
Thanks

Comment: Did you check the following usage note in project? -->  http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/archetype.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gquery-archetype to generate a gwt maven project. 
Then remove gquery dependency in the case you dont need it.
Gquery archetype is well maintained.

Do not forget to set the project name, See screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bDuv.png)

Answer (score 1):

When adding codehaus archetype try to let archetypeRepository empty. It works for me.

gquery-archetype also works.